# referential structure will typically use 64-bits or 32 bits?

Tags: python-3.x

I learned that a reference takes 64 bits :

> That is, a referential structure will typically use **64-bits** for the memory address stored in the array, on top of whatever number of bits are used to represent the object that is considered the element.

How could I see it in action?

```
In [75]: patients = ["trump", "Trump", "trumP"]
In [76]: id(patients[1])
Out[76]: 4529777048
In [77]: math.log2(4529777048)
Out[77]: 32.076792897710234
```

It's `2**32` rather than `2**64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `math.log2(id(obj))` you ask "2 raised to what power gives us the address of `obj` in the memory?".

This is not how [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) works. `id()` gives you a constant and unique value for every object. In CPython this is the address of the object in the memory.

On 64 bit systems it makes sense to store this address in a 64-bit variable since you would not be able to cover the full address-space with a 32 bit variable.

However a 64 bit reference does not mean, that every object has the address of `2**64`. As of 2018 this would not even be possible since our x86_64 pcs have [just a 48-bit address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details). That the id of your first patient was near `2**32` is (mostly) coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

`id` will return the address in memory. So, this is not what you are looking for.

Typically a way to get the size in memory of something in Python is using `sys.getsizeof()`. However, this will return the size of the object. You are interested in the size of the reference to that object.

You can however still calculate this more or less as follows: `8 * struct.calcsize("P")`. This will basically reveal if you are on a 32-bit or 64-bit system, and therefore you know what the size of a reference is. But really calculating it by inspecting a reference, I don't know if that is possible.